# Bind / Unbind inside callback

Tags: jquery, dynamic, callback, bind

I'm having all sorts of problems from the crap browser that I can't seem to overcome with anything I've read. Here's the situation... I'm using a third party plugin to generate a gallery. This plugin comes with a callback on picture change that fires each time the image is changed.

What i'm trying to do is add the css for two div's... one that is a wrapper div which will slide out when the child div is clicked and slide back in when the child is clicked again.

Here's the callback:

```
        changepicturecallback: function(){
                    $('.sxpp_commentsImage').unbind(toggle);
    oldWidth = $('.pp_pic_holder').width() - 20,
    newWidth = $('.pp_pic_holder').width() + (200),
    newHeight = $('.pp_hoverContainer').height(),
    cImageAlign = newWidth - 20;

                var toggle = function() {
                   if(newWidth == $('.sxpp_comments').width()){
                        $('.sxpp_comments').animate({width: oldWidth});
                            }else{
                        $('.sxpp_comments').animate({width: newWidth});
                    }
                }

            $('.sxpp_comments').width(oldWidth).css('background-color','red'); 
      $('.sxpp_commentsImage').css({'float':'right','background-color':'green','width':'20px','height':newHeight});     
            $('.sxpp_commentsImage').bind('click',toggle);      
  }
```

This works perfectly fine in FF4 & Chrome...however, it's as if the "bind" isn't happening in Internet Explorer. I've been reading up on the ".live" & ".delegate" methods but (A) I'm not familiar with how they work (B) If it's possible to clear that ".live" on the change then add it back as I'm doing with the bind.

Any insight or things I might be overlooking??

Edit***... The divs are created dynamically (a lightbox is shown) when a link is clicked. So the from all I'm reading... the bind event is the wrong route to go anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to unbind event funciton inside it's callback just use this:

```
$('body').bind('click', function(evt){
    console.log('I will be written only once');
    $(this).unbind(evt);
})
```

Comment: this unbind working but what if I want to bind this event again right behind unbind ?

Comment: then use functions,

Answer (score 1):

- `bind()` is for elements which are there when the page loads. Good for static.
- `live()` is the only solution for dynamically generated elements. Only choice for dynamic.

You should unbind events like `click` or `toggle`, not actual function names, which might be your problem.

Comment: I agree it should be the live()... however, when the picture is changed... it would cause the live() to be stacked on top of each other. Is there a way to clear the previous live() before adding the next one?

Comment: Why would it stack? Can't you have a global function which takes care of all those elements?

Comment: Well... I hadn't thought about moving the "var toggle = " out of the callback and making it global... my n00bness shining through. So I moved it out of the callback and added "$('.sxpp_commentsImage').live('click',toggle);" however, still has the same effect in IE.

Comment: You can use `$(this)` in your functions to reference the element which activated the event. It's useful.

Comment: well... I've switched the unbind/bind with die/live. After trying to figure out what is going on... I'm still getting stuck as all heck. I've even tried to make it more basic than that and only add a click event with an alert so I can see that the live event is being applied. It's not. So it's as if the live event is being applied as the div is being created or something. I have no idea... I hate IE.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.sxpp_commentsImage').unbind("click", toggle);
```

instead of

```
$('.sxpp_commentsImage').unbind(toggle);
```

Edit:

Or use:

```
$('.sxpp_commentsImage').bind('click.myEvent', toggle);
```

and then

```
$('.sxpp_commentsImage').unbind('click.myEvent');
```

as toggle would not be declared by the time you do the unbind.